# Calling linked server from trigger

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I've created `instead of trigger` in server A, in which I call a procedure, which in turn calls other procedure in linked server (server B).

Trigger(A) -> Procedure (A) -> Procedure (B)

But, when trigger executes it throws following error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "xxx" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".
>   Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "xxx" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

When I do this: Procedure (A) -> Procedure (B) it works perfectly. What can be the reason?

How can I fix this? Is distributed query differ from Linked server query?

Comment: Have you got MSDTC configured on both machines ?

Comment: @M.Ali, but if it was not configured, would calling Procedure(Server A) -> Procedure(Server B) work? Since it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use DTC if you use linked servers within a trigger  (not recommended as it's not performing well and your transaction will be aborted if there are any connection issues)

or

your Procedure (A) may populate some queue table, and then some scheduled task may read that queue table and run Procedure B.

or

use Replication or CDC (change data capture)  + scheduled task to trigger Procedure B on remote server

or

use Local Service Broker

Comment: thanks. 2 and 3 will not work since I have to do this immediately and job works by schedule, and both proc A and B should accept parameters. How can I use step 1 and 4? Couldn't find examples. And, why this problem even arises, we have linked servers, shouldn't it work without configuring some other settings, what is behind the scenes?

Comment: Sher, that is by design: "A distributed query that is wrapped in a trigger, even with no transaction explicitly specified, is also treated as a distributed transaction."  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/274348

Comment: As for (4), look into https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70a184f4-6c29-441e-85de-b2bc553fee4f/how-to-run-insertupdate-statement-to-linked-server-via-sql-server-broker?forum=sqlservicebroker

Comment: (2):  technically you can start a job within a trigger, so it's not necessary to schedule it, but you have to check whether job is already running (e.g. initiated by previous insert) and implement some logic to process the remaining records (if any) when the job is done.

Comment: (3): with transactional replication, the change normally is delivered within a few seconds (or milliseconds) when replication agent is running continuously. You can create a update/insert trigger on subscriber which will do your tasks.